# Create a public tunnel that points to a foreign public IP to access a game server

Tags: linux, networking, tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I have a server that I have SSH access to, let's say `34.91.54.12`.

There is another server somewhere in the internet, I have no access to, let's say `54.123.65.13`. This server is hosting a game server on port, say 2342.(Both UDP and TCP)

So, basically, a game server is hosted on `54.123.65.13:2342`.

Now, I need to create a tunnel from `34.91.54.12` to `54.123.65.13` such that, connecting to `34.91.54.12:2342` from anywhere in the internet takes me to `54.123.65.13:2342`.

So `34.91.54.12` would act like its hosting the same game server. You query either of this address, both should return the same result. Yes, the latency would be much higher through a tunnel.

What I need is the packets sent to `34.91.54.12:2342` should go through(not redirect) to `54.123.65.13:2342`. So `54.123.65.13` would see the connection coming from 34.91.54.12(This kind of looks like a proxy)

Comment: So what's your question? What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Actually you don't want to do that. You want to accept packets from anywhere and readdress them to the server actual. This is just an iptable rule. No tunnel needed.

Comment: You would need to have access to both servers in order to setup a tunnel. You cannot do it just from one side. But as @davidgo pointed out, you dont need to create a tunnel. This just introduced unnecessary latency. What you are talking about is using your server as a proxy. What you can do as well would be some sort of complicated NAT configuration, if your server supports it. Much easier would be to just use a FQDN to connect to the right server.

Comment: @davidgo so doing that just redirect the traffics right? I want the packets to go through 34.91.54.12

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What I need is the packets sent to 34.91.54.12:2342 should go through(not redirect) to 54.123.65.13:2342. So 54.123.65.13 would see the connection coming from 34.91.54.12(This kind of looks like a proxy)

Comment: @ManuShamil You are the only one talking about redirection. Everyone else is talking about forwarding. (Though it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so it's not clear what solution would solve your problem. What are you expecting to gain for the extra latency?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I will explain the real problem. I have my home PC which Is behind a NAT i have no access to and then a server which is open which I could use to tunnel the traffic to my home PC. I have tried SSH tunneling and it works perfectly. but only for webservers. It doesn't work for game servers(probably because of UDP?)

Comment: Your comment says you have complete control over the game server but your question says you have no access to it. Is the game server a machine you have complete control over and can run tunneling software on?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok lets say that I have access to the game server machine and have complete control and could turn on the tunneling machine. Can I do it?

Comment: @ManuShamil Sure. Run a tunnel on both the game server and the server machine you have access to. You can use any VPN/tunneling software you like.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please help me set it up. I tried it already, it works for web servers. but it doesn't work for game servers. I tried doing ssh -R from my home PC to the server. only apps I can access to are the web servers but no game servers probably due to the use of UDP?

Comment: You can't use SSH for UDP. You'll need to use some tunneling software that supports UDP. I personally like tinc, but it's a bit more difficult to set up than some others.